# Angular reactive form valueChanges function to detect and store only changed fields

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

Upon submitting the form, I want to capture only the values of the fields that have been changed.

Using the valueChanges function on the form captures every field of the form and it can't be traversed as an array as I've tried to do in my code below.

I'm not sure of any other way the 'before and after' values of a form can be compared and stored where only the fields that were changed are stored.

```
export class JobEditComponent implements OnInit {
jobNumber: any;
jobs: any[];
jobToEdit: Job;
job: any;
brands: Brand[];
jobForm: FormGroup;
bsConfig: Partial<BsDatepickerConfig>;
isFormReady: any;
jobId: number;
existingValues: string[] = [];
changedValues: string[] = [];


constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute,
  private jobService: JobService,
  private fb: FormBuilder,
  private router: Router,
  private alertify: AlertifyService) { }

ngOnInit() {
  this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
    this.jobNumber = +params['id'];
    });

    this.jobService.getJobToEdit().subscribe((jobs: Job[]) => {
      this.jobs = jobs;
    }, error => { console.log('error');
    }, () => {
      this.jobToEdit = this.jobs.find(j => j.id === this.jobNumber);
      this.editJobForm();
      this.onChanges();
    });

    this.getBrands();

    this.bsConfig = {
      containerClass: 'theme-blue'
    };
  }

onChanges(): void {
  this.jobForm.valueChanges.subscribe(val => {
    if (this.existingValues != null) {
      this.existingValues = val;
    }
  });
}


editJobForm() {
  this.jobForm = this.fb.group({
    jobNumber: [this.jobToEdit.jobNumber, Validators.required],
    item: [this.jobToEdit.item, Validators.required],
    status: [this.jobToEdit.status, Validators.required],
    orderedBy: [this.jobToEdit.orderedBy, Validators.required],
    orderDate: [this.jobToEdit.orderDate, Validators.required],
    quantity: [this.jobToEdit.quantity, Validators.required],
    unitPrice: [this.jobToEdit.unitPrice, Validators.required],
    lineValue: [this.jobToEdit.lineValue, Validators.required],
    dpAp: [this.jobToEdit.dpAp, Validators.required],
    eta: [this.jobToEdit.eta, Validators.required],
    detailStatus: [this.jobToEdit.detailStatus, Validators.required],
    comments: [this.jobToEdit.comments, null]
  }, ); this.isFormReady = true;
}

updateJob() {
  this.alertify.confirm('Are you sure you want save changes?', () => {
  this.jobId = this.jobToEdit.id;
  this.jobToEdit = Object.assign({}, this.jobForm.value);
  this.jobService.editJob(this.jobToEdit, this.jobId).subscribe(() => {
    this.alertify.success('Update successful');
    **for (let i = 0; i < this.existingValues.length; i++) {
      if (this.jobToEdit[i] !== this.existingValues[i]) {
         this.changedValues[i] = this.jobToEdit[i];
      }
    }**
    console.log(this.changedValues);
  }, error => {
    this.alertify.error(error);
  }, () => {
    this.router.navigate(['/home']);
  });
});
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this for your loop:

```
// declare changedValues as key -> val object (not array)
changedValues: { [key: string]: any } = {};

Object.keys(this.existingValues).forEach(i => {
  if (this.jobToEdit[i] !== this.existingValues[i]) {
     this.changedValues[i] = this.jobToEdit[i];
  }
}
```

**UPDATE**

the same loop using `for (key in object)` syntax as proposed by @Alex:

```
for (let key in this.existingValues) {
  if (this.jobToEdit[key] !== this.existingValues[key]) {
     this.changedValues[key] = this.jobToEdit[key];
  }
}
```

Comment: Assuming I have understood you correctly, Typescript gives the following error;  
  
'ts] Argument of type 'number' is not assignable to parameter of   
type '(value: string, index: number, array: string[]) => void'.  
let i: number'   
  

    for (let i = 0; i < this.existingValues.length; i++) {  
          Object.keys(this.existingValues).forEach(i) => {  
            if (this.jobToEdit[i] !== this.existingValues[i]) {  
               this.changedValues[i] = this.jobToEdit[i];  
            }  
          }

Comment: I have a mistype at my code (')' after 'i'), also, I assumed that `this.jobToEdit[i]` is a string, but I think it can be an object as well (I will change its type to 'any') so I will update my code with these two fixes

Answer (score 0):

You can check the values on submit, instead of using `valueChanges`, so if your form would look like this:

```ts
constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {
  this.myForm = this.fb.group({
    field1: [this.values.field1],
    field2: [this.values.field2],
    field3: [this.values.field3]
  })
}
```

you can on submit check the values of the properties and see if they match:

```ts
// 'values' is 'myForm.values'
onSubmit(values) {
  let changed = {};
  for (let ctrl in values) {
    if(values[ctrl] !== this.values[ctrl]) {
      changed[ctrl] = values[ctrl];
    }
  }
  console.log(changed);
}
```

Here's a

### [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-3fotxz?file=app/app.component.ts)